# What's the best way to do this: inquiry/ticket system?

Tags: custom-post-types, woocommerce-offtopic

I am working on a plugin and I want to create a system for WooCommerce users to make inquiries, and then allow a conversation, negotiation, etc.

I am thinking to create a custom post type "inquiry" and enable comments on it, add a form for the user to create such a post type, and make these posts only visible to admin and the user that created them. And admin and user could communicate via comments.

What do you think? any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a custom post type "conversation" with several post meta

```
Post meta: number of messages
Post meta: message_1
Post meta: message_1_author
Post meta: message_1_timeline
```

When displaying a conversation I check against "number of messages"

```
for (i=1; i<=nr_messages; i++){
show_message(i);
```